# What are the requirements for the capacitors on input and output side for the AMS1117 voltage regulator?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, voltage-regulator

Looking at this module to convert a supply voltage into 3.3 V for boards with the ESP8266 chip, I don't understand why there are two capacitors on both input and output side:

[image]

As far as I can tell, there is nothing about that in the datasheet: http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf

I don't have this module, but I have an AMS1117 and would like to use it to convert 5 V from a USB power supply into 3.3 V for my ESP-01S board. Do I need two capacitors on both sides, too? What's the reason for this? I'm trying to keep things as simple as possible.

Comment: Cout(s) is clearly in the datasheet. Cin(s) is most likely for decoupling. Is your question "Why are the two (on each side)?" or "Why are they there (at all)?"

Comment: @Tyler Both I guess? ;)

Comment: The requirements are quite similar between all 1117-type regulators. Sure, some datasheets might say slightly different values based on capacitor type. If some datasheet does not mention capacitor requirements, change to a better datasheet. The AMS1117 datasheet does say why output capacitance is required and how the values are chosen.

Comment: real capacitors have a frequency response different from ideal capacitors (because they have inductance and resistance in addition to capacitance). Using different sizes in parallel helps to mitigate that fact.

Comment: The values of the capacitors is written above them (106 and 104). That means you have a 100nF part in parallel with 10uF. This is intended to give you a wider frequency response than either one alone. The 10uF output part is probably also required for stability.